# Can I tell if a users Google password is SHA1 or SHA512?

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-directory-api

I want to tell if a Google account's password is stored as SHA1 or SHA512. Is there an easy way to do that?

I'm asking because I have a "google-api-php-client" (according to composer.json its branch dev-master: 1.1.x-dev). I would like to know whether this is storing SHA1 or SHA512 passwords on Google? When I greped the code base for 'SHA' all I see is the '/src/Google/IO/cacerts.pem' that specifies a fingerprint for the cert. I went through the code and it looks like it's building using Google Directory API to PUT a setPassword().

https://travis-ci.org/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

No. You have no way to know that.
You can know whether it is a plain password or a hashed password by looking at the password strenght assessment at the admin control panel, though.